# BlackBerry - Programmatically create new exception in profile?

Tags: blackberry, operating-system, integration, notifications

Actually i trying **how to read the profile status** but i am not getting that.

....

If anyone have an idea how to create new exception in profile programmatically,

will really helpful for me.

Thanks